# How to set profile location for New Relic Cli

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am using an profile file which is not default in ~/.aws/profiles. It currently located at D:/xxx.ini, and the profile name is [deployProfile], How can I pass this profile to the new relic cli to install the lambda layer? The official doc gives this

```
newrelic-lambda layers install \
-f [FUNCTION_NAME] \
--nr-account-id 1594121
```

and it says `AWS_PROFILE` env variable or `--aws-profile` argument may helps, but I don't know how to combine the profile name with the file location.
is there anything like the aws cli's "-ProfileLocation"?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to set the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable to the location of the file?

So, export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/location/of/the/file.ini" or, since it seems that your using windows, something like set AWS_CONFIG_FILE="D:/xxx.ini"